# magento grid search is not triggered if both search term and filters unchanged

Tags: magento2, grid, search

In magento grid setting, by default the search request call (ajax call) is not triggered if search term and filter remain unchanged since last search.

How can I force it to send out search request every time I click the fulltext **magnifying-glass** icon or the **Ａpply Filters** button under expanded filter panel?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that uses **uiRegistry**. Here is the code

```
    function reloadGrid() {
      var grid = 'abc.abc_data_source';
        if(grid) {
            var params = [];
            var target = registry.get(grid);
            if (target && typeof target === 'object') {
                target.set('params.t ', Date.now());
            }
       }
     }
```

I created a new button on the grid page and then bind the above function to a its click event.

I believe that there are other better solutions. if you happen to know that, please share it here. thanks.